# How to use Google Maps API v3 ClientID in application > Webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

Need to get Google Map V3 API work in .net application with purchased ClientID.

The application is using WebBrowser Control to load html into documentText and the Url is 'about:blank'. The problem is I can't put about:blank into authorized URLs list in google map console. Also I can't host html as it needs a lot of data from database. It must be in application.

Can anyone help me how to use google map clientID in application without an url or url = localhost? Is there any way to trick web browser control to use localhost as url but use html in code? Because I can add localhost into white list. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the `OAuth 2.0` instead of a `Public API access` key; however if you have to `Public API access`, you should use the `Key for server applications`, and set it to accept all IP by setting the IP to `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a try and post the result.

Comment: Will use Public API key to achieve this. Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: With ClientID, google support actually has to manually add 'about:blank' into white list.